# Добавление множества объектов в массив

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть массив допустим:

```
var points = [[52.0625,142.962494],[52.0625,143.129166],[52.054165,142.995834],[52.054165,143.079163],[52.054165,143.145828], ...]
```

Я пробегаю циклом и забираю только значения и кладу их в объект:

```
  $.each(points, function(k, v){
      var myArray = [];
      var myObject = {
        "lat": v[0],
        "lon": v[1]
      }
});
```

Есть так же пустой массив

```
var myArray = [];
```

при таком раскладе:

```
myArray.push(myObject);
  console.log(myArray)
```

Выводится:

[Object]
[Object]
[Object]
[Object]
[Object]
[Object]
[Object]
...

А мне надо положить все объекты в пусто массив myArray = [];
чтобы consol.log выдавало вот так:

```
[Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, …]
```

Не могу понять где моя ошибка?
Подскажите пожалуйста. Заранее благодарен!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Объявление `myArray` нужно вынести за пределы функции в `each`, ибо сейчас у вас на каждом шаге цикла создается новый массив, который в итоге содержит лишь один элемент, и доступ к которому за пределами цикла отсутсвует:

```js
var points = [
    [52.0625, 142.962494],
    [52.0625, 143.129166],
    [52.054165, 142.995834],
    [52.054165, 143.079163],
    [52.054165, 143.145828]
  ],
  myArray = [];

$.each(points, function(k, v) {
  var myObject = {
    "lat": v[0],
    "lon": v[1]
  };
  
  myArray.push(myObject);
});

console.log(myArray);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: «за пределами» **функции**, а не цикла. Можно в коде ТС просто убрать объявление массива внутри ф-ии, и код заработает.

Comment: Спасибо большое!!! Мелочь вроде а я всю голову сломал)))

Answer (score 2):

Константин правильно [ответил](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/552238/7161) на непосредственный вопрос о том, где ошибка в вашем коде.

Добавлю, что вашу задачу элегантнее решить чуть иначе: использовать стандартный метод [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) – функция внутри применится к каждому элементу массива, а на выходе вы сразу получите новый массив с «переделанными» элементами:

```js
var points = [[52.0625,142.962494],[52.0625,143.129166],[52.054165,142.995834],[52.054165,143.079163],[52.054165,143.145828],];
var myArray = points.map( function(el){
    return {
        lat: el[0],
        lon: el[1]
    };
});

document.body.innerHTML = JSON.stringify( myArray);
```

Это чистый JavaScript, не требует доп. библиотек вроде jQuery. В jQuery есть [похожий метод](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/), усложнять **не нужно**, но для общего развития, можно и так:

```
// изменения только в этой строке:
var myArray = $.map(points, function(el){
```

Comment: Круто!!! Спасибо большое!!!